# Restrict php code in wordpress using woocommerce membership

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to restrict a php code in my theme files using woocommerce membership plugin but I don't know how!

I see that the plugin offers a shortcode to restrict content inside editor but I don't know how to implement it in a php file.

The shortcode is :
[wcm_restrict]
[/wcm_restrict]

Here's the code I want to restrict:

```
<?php
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
 
    return $data;
}

function get_domain_name($url){
    $domain =   parse_url($url);
    return $domain['host'];
}

function getUrlData($url)
{
    $result = false;
    $contents = getUrlContents($url);

    if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
    {
        $title = null;
        $metaTags = null;

        preg_match('/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si', $contents, $match );

        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) > 0)
        {
            $title = strip_tags($match[1]);
        }

        preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*name="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' .'[lang="]*[^>"]*["]*'.'[\s]*content="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);
        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 3)
        {
            $originals = $match[0];
            $names = $match[1];
            $values = $match[2];

            if (count($originals) == count($names) && count($names) == count($values))
            {
                $metaTags = array();

                for ($i=0, $limiti=count($names); $i < $limiti; $i++)
                {
                    $metaname=trim(strtolower($names[$i]));
                    $metaname=str_replace("'",'',$metaname);
                    $metaname=str_replace("/",'',$metaname);
                    $metaTags[$metaname] = array (
                    'html' => htmlentities($originals[$i]),
                    'value' => $values[$i]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        if(sizeof($metaTags)==0) {
            preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*content="?' . '([^>"]*)"?[\s]*' .'[lang="]*[^>"]*["]*'.'[\s]*name="?([^>"]*)"?[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

            if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 3)
            {
                $originals = $match[0];
                $names = $match[2];
                $values = $match[1];

                if (count($originals) == count($names) && count($names) == count($values))
                {
                    $metaTags = array();

                    for ($i=0, $limiti=count($names); $i < $limiti; $i++)
                    {
                        $metaname=trim(strtolower($names[$i]));
                        $metaname=str_replace("'",'',$metaname);
                        $metaname=str_replace("/",'',$metaname);
                        $metaTags[$metaname] = array (
                            'html' => htmlentities($originals[$i]),
                            'value' => $values[$i]
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $result = array (
            'title' => $title,
            'metaTags' => $metaTags
        );
    }

    return $result;
}

function getUrlContents($url, $maximumRedirections = null, $currentRedirection = 0)
{
    $result = false;
    $contents = $url;

    if (isset($contents) && is_string($contents))
    {
        preg_match_all('/<[\s]*meta[\s]*http-equiv="?REFRESH"?' . '[\s]*content="?[0-9]*;[\s]*URL[\s]*=[\s]*([^>"]*)"?' . '[\s]*[\/]?[\s]*>/si', $contents, $match);

        if (isset($match) && is_array($match) && count($match) == 2 && count($match[1]) == 1)
        {
            if (!isset($maximumRedirections) || $currentRedirection < $maximumRedirections)
            {
                return getUrlContents($match[1][0], $maximumRedirections, ++$currentRedirection);
            }

            $result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = $contents;
        }
    }

    return $contents;
}

function truncate_string ($string, $maxlength, $extension) {
   $cutmarker = "**cut_here**";
   if (strlen($string) > $maxlength) {
       $string = wordwrap($string, $maxlength, $cutmarker);
       $string = explode($cutmarker, $string);
       $string = $string[0] . $extension;
   }

   return $string;
}



$url    = isset($_POST["url"]) ? trim(strip_tags($_POST["url"])) : '';


if($_POST){

if(substr($url, 0, 4) != "http"){   
    echo '<br /><br /><h3 class="tool-center">Please enter full web page URL including http://</h3>';
    exit(); 
}

$domain =   get_domain_name($url);
$domain = str_replace("www.","",$domain);

$content = file_get_contents_curl($url);
$result = getUrlData($content);

$title=isset($result['title']) ? $result['title'] : '';
$title_length = strlen($title);
$description=isset($result['metaTags']['description']['value']) ? $result['metaTags']['description']['value'] : '';
$desc_length = strlen($description);
$descriptiont = trim(trim(truncate_string($description,255,"..."),"/"),"'");
$keywords=isset($result['metaTags']['keywords']['value']) ? $result['metaTags']['keywords']['value'] : '';
$keywords_length = strlen($keywords);
$keywordst = trim(trim(truncate_string($keywords,255,"..."),"/"),"'");

$h1 = 0;
$h2 = 0;
$h3 = 0;
$h4 = 0;
$h5 = 0;
$h6 = 0;

$h1_t = "";
$h2_t = "";
$h3_t = "";
$h4_t = "";
$h5_t = "";
$h6_t = "";         

preg_match_all('/<h([1-6])(.*?)>(.*?)<\/(h[1-6])>/is',$content,$h_tags);
if(isset($h_tags[4])){
foreach ($h_tags[4] as $k => $h){

    $h = strtolower($h);
    if($h == "h1"){
        $h1++;
        $h1_t .= "<br> -        ".trim(strip_tags($h_tags[3][$k]))."    ";
    }
    if($h == "h2"){ 
        $h2++;
        $h2_t .= "<br> -        ".trim(strip_tags($h_tags[3][$k]))."    ";
    }
    if($h == "h3"){ 
        $h3++; 
        $h3_t .= "<br> -        ".trim(strip_tags($h_tags[3][$k]))."    ";
    }
    if($h == "h4"){ 
        $h4++; 
        $h4_t .= "<br> -        ".trim(strip_tags($h_tags[3][$k]))."    ";
    }
    if($h == "h5"){ 
        $h5++; 
        $h5_t .= "<br> -        ".trim(strip_tags($h_tags[3][$k]))."    ";
    }
    if($h == "h6"){ 
        $h6++; 
        $h6_t .= "<br> -        ".trim(strip_tags($h_tags[3][$k]))."    ";
    }       
}
}

preg_match_all('#<img(.*?)(>|/>)#is',$content,$img_links);
$img_count = 0;
if(isset($img_links[0])){
foreach ($img_links[0] as $img_link){
    $img_count++;
}
}

$internal_links = 0;
$external_links = 0;
preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)<\/a>/is',$content,$page_links);
if(isset($page_links[0])){
foreach ($page_links[0] as $key => $link){
    
    preg_match('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)<\/a>/is',$link,$anchor_link);
    if(isset($anchor_link[2])){
    if(trim(strip_tags($anchor_link[2])) != ""){
    if(substr($anchor_link[2], 0, 4) != "http"){
        $internal_links++;      
    }else{
    preg_match("/$domain/is",$anchor_link[2],$check_link);
        
        if (isset($check_link[0])) {
            $internal_links++;
        }else{          
            $external_links++;          
        }   
    }
    }
    }

}
}
?>
<br /><br />
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="30%"><strong>Title</strong></td>
    <td width="70%"><?php echo $title; ?><br /><br />Length: <?php echo $title_length; ?> characters</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Meta Keywords</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $keywordst; ?><br /><br />Length: <?php echo $keywords_length; ?> characters</td>    
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Meta Description</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $descriptiont; ?><br /><br />Length: <?php echo $desc_length; ?> characters</td> 
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>H1</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $h1; ?> tags<br /><?php echo $h1_t; ?></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>H2</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $h2; ?> tags<br /><?php echo $h2_t; ?></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>H3</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $h3; ?> tags<br /><?php echo $h3_t; ?></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>H4</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $h4; ?> tags<br /><?php echo $h4_t; ?></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>H5</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $h5; ?> tags<br /><?php echo $h5_t; ?></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>H6</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $h6; ?> tags<br /><?php echo $h6_t; ?></td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Total Images</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $img_count; ?> images</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Internal Links</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $internal_links; ?> internal links</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>External Links</strong></td>
    <td><?php echo $external_links; ?> external links</td>  
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce memberships extension will provide support for this as its a premium extension however there will be a function you can use to restrict.

https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-memberships-function-reference/

You want only execute the code for members using a conditional tag like this

```
if ( wc_memberships_is_product_viewing_restricted() ) {
    echo $output;
}
```

Where $output equals your HTML.

The conditional depends on exactly what you want to do.